# How to send and receive numeric list from C# to Python?

Tags: c#, python

I'm new to Python and I have to send some lists of double type from C# to Python and receive a list in return.
Here is the C# code:

```
private List<double> func_C(List<double> sampleX, List<double> sampleY, List<double> DBx, List<double> DBy)
    {
        var python = "python.exe";
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        FileInfo pfile = new FileInfo(python);        
        var filename = "mypython.py";
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(filename);
        var filepath = directory.FullName;
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = filepath
            + " " + sampleX 
            + " " + sampleY
            + " " + DBx
            + " " + DBy;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
        FileInfo fileinfor = new FileInfo(filename);

        myProcess.Start();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        sampleY.Clear();
        string readum= string.Empty;
        while((readum = myStreamReader.ReadLine())!= null)
            sampleY.Add(Double.Parse(readum));

        Console.WriteLine("runpython 5" + myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("runpython 6" + myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        myProcess.Close();            
        myProcess.Refresh(); 
        return sampleY;
    }
```

This my python code:

```
 import sys 
 import numpy as np
 XY = np.array(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
 XY2 = np.array(sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
 # Some operations done
 print(XY[1])
```

I received this error

> XY = np.array(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
>          TypeError: data type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]

not understood
How to send lists to Python from C#?

Comment: sorry to ask, why mixing c# and python? wont IronPython help?

Comment: @MEdwin We need to run some python scripts in C#.

Comment: Can you add command created by C# and values `sys.argv[...]`?

Comment: @Poolka sys.argv[...] was working with single value. But now I'm sending list as an argument which is not working. Can you help me in this?

Comment: In Python you may do `print(sys.argv)` or `print(sys.argv[...])` to see the data you gonna work with. Add this info into the question.

Comment: @Poolka I did `for x in sys.argv[1]: print(x)`, but I got this `Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll`.

Comment: This is C# syntax not Python syntax. Also it is not full exception message. Anyway if I understand correctly C# script creates command (actual text) to run python script. What text is created? Print it in C#. Print it in Python before any processing. Add those strings to the question.